# Is there a way to change the behavior of dead keys on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I started using linux a few weeks ago and, while the layout of my keyboard is correctly set and suits me, the behavior of some keys (mostly the " key) bothers me.

In Windows, if I press that key (") it fist shows nothing and waits for my next input to decide if it'll be a diaeresis symbol with a letter (ä) or just a double quote if there's no possible composition with my new input.

When I press it using Ubuntu, it inputs a clear diaeresis symbol (¨) and composes it with my next input if it has a possible composition. The problem is, with every character that has no possible composition it simply clears itself, writing neither the character nor the diaeresis symbol. And the only way of getting a double quote is pressing space after it.

In addition, in some places the behavior is even more annoying. When I'm using spyder (programming uses a lot of double quotes), if I write the diaeresis symbol (first step to make double quotes) and try to delete it (with backspace) it stays in place and deletes the chars that were before it, if I write again over it, it stays there. The only way of getting rid of it is to write another diaeresis and make it into a double quote, then deleting it.

If possible, I would like to change this behavior.

Comment: Can you give us an app and some normal keystrokes that cause this?  " works for me in Terminal and in Libre Office.  Ubuntu 18.04.  Standard Laptop Keyboard

Comment: You might consider checking in http://Askubuntu.com as well; not posting a duplicate question, but just checking, since this is an Ubuntu-centric issue. Also, which version of Ubuntu is in use? Lots more folks over there focused on Ubuntu, and one might have solved it.